# Apache Ignite is too slow when execute concurrent queries

Tags: performance, ignite

I have a table (15M rows) which is imported in two databases:

- Ignite 2.14
- MySql 8.0

There are two test cases:

1. **Single execute** `SELECT count(*) from table_name` - 2 seconds for both databases.
2. **Multi-threaded (100 threads)** executions with exactly the same query - 30 seconds (MySQL), 80 seconds (Ignite).

I found out that Ignite is too slow, or is this something that I missed in the configuration?

Comment: What is your configuration? How many nodes do you have? What is the query? How did you create your table?

Comment: @jimmy is `SELECT count(*) from table_name` the only query you test? If you ask me you should test with real queries, testing with synthetic queries (like count(*)) doesn't make too much sense in general.

Comment: @StephenDarlington it seems to be 3 nodes with 16GB RAM for each (Ignite), I am not very clear about that (I am not setting up them). My table is created with template which Im not pretty clear, but it contains only 4-5 simple columns. I am new with Ignite and trying to do some performance tests with it, and what I am confusing it takes too much time in the very common case (I think).

Comment: @VladimirPligin  actually the first query of mine is more complex with INNER JOIN, and the performance is even worse. So that I am trying to do test with simplest query. Please be clear that I am just confusing about Ignite performance under concurrent queries, I am not trying to compare Ignite with MySql.

Comment: I appreciate that you're new to Ignite, but I don't think anyone can help without some configuration information.